# List of inherited classes with mixed properties

Tags: c#, list, linq, inheritance

I'm making an RPG, and I set up the item system using inherited classes, but I'm having difficulties figuring out how to get a subset of the list for a shop that allows me to filter them out using properties of all the classes.

Here is a trimmed down version of what I'm running into:

```
    public class GameItem
    {
        public string strName;
        public int intQuantity;
        public int intItemType;
    }

    public class GeneralItem : GameItem
    {
        public int intTargetType;
    }

    public class EquipmentItem : GameItem
    {
        public int intAttackPower;
        public int intDefensePower;
        public int intEquipmentType;
        public bool blnEquippableByPlayer1;
    }

    private void GetShopItems()
    {
        Items.Add(new GeneralItem() { strName = "Healing Potion", intItemType = 2, intQuantity = 10, intTargetType = 0 });
        Items.Add(new EquipmentItem() { intItemType = 0, intEquipmentType = 0, blnEquippableByPlayer1 = true, strName = "Sword", intQuantity = 1, intAttackPower = 10, intDefensePower = 2 });
        Items.Add(new EquipmentItem() { intItemType = 0, intEquipmentType = 1, blnEquippableByPlayer1 = false, strName = "Armor", intQuantity = 1, intAttackPower = 10, intDefensePower = 2 });

        //cannot convert GeneralItem to GameItemEquipment
        List<GameItem> ShopItems = Items.Where(x => x.intQuantity > 0 && ((EquipmentItem)x).blnEquippableByPlayer1).ToList(); 
    }
```

I need to do this because I want to display all the items regardless of type in the shop. Since all the items are not Equipment, it fails when it get to the healing potion.

Answer (score 2):

You're filter must first check if the item is equipment:

```
.Where(x => x.intQuantity > 0 && (x is not EquipmentItem || (x as EquipmentItem).blnEquippableByPlayer1))
```

Having said that I think the item could itself control if it's available for shopping:

In `GameItem`:

```
public virtual bool IsAvailableInShop() => intQuantity > 0;
```

In `EquipmentItem`:

```
public override bool IsAvailableInShop() 
    => base.IsAvailableInShop() && blnEquippableByPlayer1;
```

and then

```
var ShopItems = Items.Where(x => x.IsAvailableInShop());
```

Comment: I implemented both of your suggestions, and they worked wonderfully, thank you very much.